# Can you use getchar() to assign elements in an array? [C]

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that takes an inputted sentence and turns it into "internet lingo." (B1FF-speak)
Example:

```
Enter message: Hey dude, C is rilly cool
In B1FF-speak: H3Y DUD3, C 15 R1LLY C00L!!!!!!!!!!
```

And I was wondering if I was able to use `getchar()` to assign the different elements in my array.
**I just realized that the reason my code was printing so many characters before the `!!!!!!!` was because of the array size, I'm changing that now**

```
#define N 50
#define SIZE ((int) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])))

int main(void)
{
    int a[N] = {0}, i, j;

    printf("Enter message: ");

    for(j = 0, i = 0;; j++, i++)
    {
        a[i] = getchar();
        if (a[i] = '\n')
            break;
    }

    printf("In B1FF-speak: ");
    for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        switch (toupper(a[i]))
        {
            case 'A':
            printf("4");
            break;

            case 'B':
            printf("8");
            break;

            case 'E':
            printf("3");
            break;

            case 'I':
            printf("1");
            break;

            case 'O':
            printf("0");
            break;

            case 'S':
            printf("5");
            break;

            default:
            putchar(a[i]);
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("!!!!!!!!!!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your loop condition can never be false...

Comment: add condition 'i<N' in for loop so that it wont exceed array size

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Are you having a problem with your code?

Comment: There is an obvious bug in that you always output 50 different things, instead of stopping at the count of however many characters the person typed

Comment: @MattMcNabb now the issue is that it won't print the characters when it gets to the switch, it just goes through the for statement without every printing anything

Comment: @Nicolas print a `\n` at the end of the `!!!!`. And change `if (a[i] = '\n')` to `if (a[i] == '\n')`

Comment: also do `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <ctype.h>`

Answer (score 0):

1. > I was wondering if I was able to use getchar() to assign the different elements in my array.

Yes you can.

2. > I'm also having issues with the breaking statement in the first for loop, I'm not sure whether it has to do with using getchar().

To read whole line or to the ned of chars you can use this

```
int getcharRet;
while((getcharRet = getchar()) != '\n' && getcharRet != EOF)
    a[i] = getcharRet;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `if` inside your `for`-loop from

```
    if (a[i] = '\n')
```

to

```
    if (a[i] == '\n')
```

Statement (a[i] = '\n') is not condition, is it assignment.

**EDIT:**

And better input loop can be

```
   for(j = 0, i = 0; i < N-1; j++, i++)
```

when condition `i < N-1` prevent wrong indexing and segmentation fault